# installing freemarker plugin on eclipse indigo

Tags: eclipse-plugin, freemarker

I was tryi ng to install the freemarker plugin for eclipse Indigo on my machine which runs on Ubuntu 11. I tried to add http://www.freemarker.org/eclipse/update with the name FreeMarker to install new softwares option. But, it complained that there were no repositories. Then, IO manually tried to download the plugin file (freemarker-2.3.19.tar.gz) from http://sourceforge.net/projects/freemarker and tried to copy the contents to /usr/share/eclipse/plugins folder. But, it rejected it complaining that the format of the file contents were incompatible.
Can anyone please help me with this issue.
Thanks in advance.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I finally did is, I downloaded Eclipse Indigo for Java EE from Eclipse official website. It had the market place from where I could easily install the JBoss plugin. All I had to do is install it from within Eclipse and could work on freemarker after that.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the FreeMarker plugin in the JBoss Tools Project, as http://freemarker.org/editors.html says. Where did you get the link to the old plugin? (Also, freemarker-2.3.19.tar.gz is the FreeMarker distribution, and has nothing to do with Eclipse.)